# Modify other widgets with conditional statements KivyMD

Tags: kivy, conditional-statements, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to modify the state of an MDTextField based on the state of an MDCheckbox. Initially, the TextField should be disabled and non-visible. The desired result is that when the MDCheckbox state is Active or True, MDTextField will be enabled and visible, and viceversa. I am only using KVLanguage for this task.

This is my code so far, the state of my MDTextField remains unchanged even the Checkbox is active:

```
 <MyContent>:    
    MDCheckbox:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: dp(50), dp(50)
        halign:'left'
        pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.6}
        on_state:
            if self.state == 'active': \
            root.ids.numCotiz.enabled = True ; \
            root.ids.numCotiz.opacity= 1
            #else: numCotiz.enabled = False and numCotiz.opacity= 0

    MDTextField:
        id: numCotiz
        mode: "rectangle"
        enabled: False
        opacity: 0
        multiline: 'False'
        max_text_length:10
        pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.6}
        hint_text: 'Agregue numero de cotizacion'
        size_hint: 0.3, 1
```

Other alternative for the code in the MDCheckbox is as the following:

```
MDCheckbox:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: dp(50), dp(50)
        halign:'left'
        pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.6}
        on_active:
            numCotiz.enabled = True
            numCotiz.opacity= 1
```

With this alternative I do get the my TextField to appear on the screen, yet I don't know how to turn opacity = 0 again when Chechbox is unactive again.
I have done research on this matter but I can't get the desired result.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I changed my Kivy Code to:

```
MDCheckbox:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: dp(50), dp(50)
        halign:'left'
        pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.6}
        on_active:
            root.on_checkbox_active(*args)
```

And added a function on my Python file.

```
class MyContent(BoxLayout):

    def on_checkbox_active(self, checkbox, value):
        if value:
            self.ids.numCotiz.enabled= True
            self.ids.numCotiz.opacity = 1
        else:
            self.ids.numCotiz.enabled = False
            self.ids.numCotiz.opacity = 0
```

Now it works like a charm. :)